# how can we implement Input Dialog box in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d how to bring a Input dialog box for getting user name. Is there any way than using view based application?

Comment: How to add Text field in UIAlertView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d does not provide with a way of doing that. You would have to either build you own solution or use UIKit to add a UITextField for example.